# How to pass base version of aws cdk app to multiple teams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have prepared a base version of my AWS CDK app. I want to pass it to multiple teams. This teams will perform some additional operations on my base version and publish it on their environments.

For example: my Base Version is: `AWS-PipelineStack-V1`
It contains multiple stacks created as part of the app creation.

I want to pass `AWS-PipelineStack-V1` to Operations & Management Teams. This teams will add/modify few functionalities according to their requirements within the stacks in the cdk app.

How can I share my base version will multiple teams, also giving them an option to add few things to base version.

Comment: Version control such as git is the most common way.

Comment: Terraform has an option to publish your base version as modules to terraform registry and then multiple teams use this modules for their operations. Do we have something similar for aws cdk?